# Возвращаемый шаблонной функцией тип

Tags: c++, функции, visual-c++, шаблоны-с++

В книге Стенли Липпмана(Базовый курс по с++) написано, что если тип возвращаемый шаблонной функцией отличается от типа параметра шаблона, то можно использовать замыкание:

```
template<typename Iterator>
auto process(const Iterator& beg, const Iterator& end)->decltype(*beg) {
    /*SOMECODE*/
    return *end;
}
```

Вопрос 1:

Если возвращаемый тип будет результатом сложных вычислений, мне дублировать их в decltype(/*вычисления*/)?

Вопрос 2:

Какие преимущества использование замыкания по сравнению с использованием спецификатора auto для выведения возвращаемого типа (код далее)

```
template<typename Iterator>
auto process(const Iterator& beg, const Iterator& end) {
    /*SOMECODE*/
    return *end;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понимаю, что и почему вы называете "замыканием".

> Если возвращаемый тип будет результатом сложных вычислений, мне дублировать их в decltype(/вычисления/)?

Да, если вы хотите воспользоваться именно C++11 синтаксисом с `-> decltype(что-то)`.

Однако начиная с C++14 у вас есть возможность использовать `auto` (или `decltype(auto)`) в качестве типа возвращаемого значения и не указывать этот хвост с `-> decltype(что-то)` вообще. В такой ситуации тип возвращаемого значения будет выведен автоматически из типа аргумента `return`.

> Вопрос 2: Какие приемущества использование замыкания по сравнению с использованием спецификатора auto для выведения возвращаемого типа

Преимущества заключаются в том, что вариант `-> decltype(что-то)` сразу жестко задает тип возвращаемого значения функции. После этого в `return` можно указывать значения *других* типов - и они будут как обычно *приводиться* к типу возврата функции.

В выводимом варианте такой возможности нет. Если разные `return` будут возвращать значения разных типов, тот дедукция будет неоднозначной и код просто не будет компилироваться.

То есть это совершенно разные модели поведения и дело тот не в преимуществах, а в том, какая именно модель вам нужна: 1) жестко заданный тип с приведением, или 2) выводимый тип с требованием единообразия.

Comment: Такой синтаксис: auto func()->_type_{} автор указаной книги называет замыкающим типом

Comment: @Денис, это либо ошибка перевода, либо автора. Замыканием (closure) является тип, который производит на свет лямбда. Т.е. синтаксис вида `[](){}`

Comment: @ixSci если быть точнее, то синтаксис такого вида - это лямбда-выражение, тип, который оно создает - это класс замыкания или тип замыкания, а замыкание - это объект этого типа.

Answer (score 0):

Тут стоило бы начать с того, что правила вывода типа для `auto` и `decltype` различны. Например, если в качестве `Iterator` используется `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`, то возвращаемые типы будут различны:

1. экземпляр `std::string` (иницилизированный вызовом конструктора копирования).

```
template<typename Iterator>
auto process(const Iterator& beg, const Iterator& end)

template<typename Iterator>
auto process(const Iterator& beg, const Iterator& end) -> std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*beg)>
```

2. ссылка `std::string &`

```
template<typename Iterator>
decltype(auto) process(const Iterator& beg, const Iterator& end)

template<typename Iterator>
auto process(const Iterator& beg, const Iterator& end) -> decltype(*beg)
```

Кроме того, автоматический вывод типа не может быть использован, если функция вызывается до ее определения.